# Saving Large Bite() Arrays to File

Tags: .net, vb.net, byte, filestream

I'm working with an API that returns a document as a Byte() array.  My first question is what is the capacity of a Byte() array?  I ought to make sure the whole document is coming through from the API.

Assuming the Byte() array does hold the entire document in memory, what is the most efficient mechanism for saving to a local folder?

I've looked at File.WriteAllBytes but this appears to have a limit of 2MB.  I'm currently using:

```
    Dim bDocument = obj.DownloadDocument(21, oAuth) 'API call returns byte() of document
    Dim sStream As New FileStream("C:\Websites\docName.tif", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    sStream.Write(bDocument, 0, bDocument.Length)
```

But I've read that 2GB is the limit of any file size in the CLR.  What is the best way of handling and saving potential very large files?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your questions:

1. The maximum *number of elements* an array in .NET can have is 2.147.483.647 (2^31 - 1). The maximum *size* depends on the type of elements and whether you're running in a 32-bit process or 64-bit process. As such, the maximum size a *byte array* can have is the above number (2GB - 1 byte).
2. To save to a local folder, from a single array, use `File.WriteAllBytes`. If you have multiple arrays, use a stream and write each array
3. File.WriteAllBytes does not have a limit of 2 *MB*. Alone it does not have any limit, but obviously it cannot write byte arrays larger than 2GB (-1 byte), since such arrays aren't allowed in .NET
4. The maximum file size is dictated by the underlying file system, not .NET / CLR.

Side question: Have you considered just downloading the file "directly to disk"? Meaning that you would open a stream for the download and a stream for the file, and read buffer by buffer and write to the file stream as you go? This would mean that the actual limit to the size here would be the underlying file system or free space, not memory. Obviously this will only be possible if the API for whatever it is you're downloading from has support for streams.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a 3rd party system and its their API that returns documents as a byte() array. So what we're looking at here is their API will be fine for documents under 2GB only?  I'd better go back to the software vendor to check on whether they can stream documents as well.

Comment: The API will not be able to return larger documents than 2GB, perhaps that's not an issue anyway? Are you sure you can get documents that large in the first place? What kind of document is this?

Comment: Looking at this a bit more, with .Net 4.5 there is a config option:
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"></gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>
  </runtime>

Which eliminates the 2GB limit.  So the solution appears to be to upgrade to the latest framework version.

Comment: That won't help. As per the documentation the *index* restriction is still in place, which means that setting only helps with arrays containing elements that are larger than 1 byte each.